# Struts2: How to read parameters from <jsp:include>

Tags: jsp, parameters, struts2, include

When I include a JSP, either by `<jsp:include />` and specify parameters - they are perfectly accessible by EL `${param.XXX}` but not by OGNL `%{#parameters.XXX}`.

For example:

```
<jsp:include page="fragment.jsp">
    <jsp:param value="foo" name="bar" />
</jsp:include>
```

and in fragment.jsp

```
value of foo in EL   : ${param.bar} 
value of foo in OGNL : <s:property value="%{#parameters.bar}" />
```

WHY ??? What should I use instead in Struts Tags ?

Note: with `<s:include/>` instead of `<jsp:include/>`, the parameter is not accessible even with EL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13762054/1700321

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do to solve the problem:

In including page:

```
<s:set name="searchName" value="my search term" />
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/page/whatever.jsp" />
```

In /WEB-INF/page/whatever.jsp:

```
Your searchTerm is <s:property value="#searchName" />
```

I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem recently. I found the reason is that the parameters in `<s:include>` is not stored in the `request.parameters` object of `ActionContext`, but stored in `HttpServletRequest` of JSP page. So the parameters can be obtained through `EL（${param.xxx}）` or `<% request.getParameters("xxxx") %>`, but we can't get it through (struts) ongl. Because the parameters are not in the `ActionContext`.

If you insist on using the ongl, you can add the parameters into `ActionContext` through jsp `<%  %>` or EL and then you can obtain the parameters through ongl.

Answer (score 1):

http://prodia.co.uk/blog/doahh/entry/struts2_s_include_and_passing

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing something similar on included page,
<c:set var="localCopyOfParam" value="${param.realParam}"/>
...
<s:anytag value="#attr.localCopyOfParam"/>

but that's stupid isn't it?

Comment: IIf you choose struts taglib you must do it like:

| <s:set var="localCopyOfParamAjax">${param.ajax}</s:set>

Answer (score -2):

Try the following.

```
<s:property value="%{#parameters['paramName']}"></s:property>
```