# Struts2, Cannot access param using <s:include> tag. Want to use it in <s:if> tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl

I have a situation that I need to put my NAV bar at the top of each page. So I decided to Include a new JSP in each page having a parameter indicating the what is the active tab the user is on.

My Implementation is as follows.

**dashboard.jsp**

```
...
<s:include value="../tab-set.jsp">
    <s:param name="tab_name" value="dashboard" />
</s:include>
...
```

**tab-set.jsp**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li <s:if test="param.tab_name == 'dashboard'">class="active"</s:if> >
            <a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li <s:if test="param.tab_name == 'tab_2'">class="active"</s:if> >
            <a href="suggestion">TAB 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The result is that IF case do not execute on both tabs.

I have also tried it with different approaches but its not working like

`<s:if test="#param.tab_name == 'dashboard'">`

OR

`<s:if test="#attr.tab_name == 'dashboard'">` *(found some place on the net)*

OR I also tried to print the value of `tab_name` value on page using `${param.tab_name}` but nothing happened.

But none of them are working.

Please help me or guide me what I can do instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters cannot be accessed that way because valuestack is not created within rendered page. Try to access them like request parameters `${param.tab_name}`.

**Update**

The value of `<s:param>` tag should be `'dashboard'` because it is a string.

```
<s:include value="../tab-set.jsp">
    <s:param name="tab_name" value="'dashboard'" />
</s:include>
```

In your included page get `tab_name` using `${param.tab_name}` notation and set it to some other variable using `<s:set>` tag.

```
<s:set name="tabName">
   ${param.tab_name}
</s:set>
<s:if test="#tabName == 'dashboard'">
</s:if>
```

This way there is no need to use scriplets.

Comment: Sorry, not been able to understand. U mean that I set the `tab_name` param in `request` from Action class and get use it on JSP

Comment: Okay, I have also tried the way you told me and still its not working... I just print that what value i received from parent and it prints blank string. I used `${param.tab_name}` and its not printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation from the struts2 on how to use the include tag:
[documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/include.html)

Comment: That NOT going to work. Parameters in in included files must be accessed in other way.

Comment: How exactly are you passing parameters to included file? If it is like in original post then it should not work.

Comment: Fixed my answer after reading the struts2 documentation, I guess i did something wrong in the quick test I've done.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in the missing piece:

`<% pageContext.setAttribute("tab_name" , request.getParameter("tab_name")); %>`

Then, do like tihs:

**tab-set.jsp**

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("tab_name" , request.getParameter("tab_name")); %>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li <s:if test="#attr.tab_name == 'dashboard'">class="active"</s:if> >
            <a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li <s:if test="#attr.tab_name == 'tab_2'">class="active"</s:if> >
            <a href="suggestion">TAB 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Enjoy

Comment: This is using scriptlets, but will also work if `<s:param>` value inside `<s:include>` will be fixed.

Comment: Nice, not tested but +1 on trust :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Change **dashboard.jsp** File with following code :

```
<s:include value="../tab-set.jsp">
    <s:param name="tab_name">dashboard</s:param>
</s:include>
```

If you declared the “String” value inside the “value” attribute, Struts 2 will  ignore it.

Comment: You just need to tell that it is a String.