# How to refer s:iterator var of one jsp into another jsp in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jspinclude, struts-tags

I am working on a project which involves migration from Struts 1 to Struts 2 version. In one jsp, I have iterator as

```
<s:iterator var="each_part" value="#request.rule.parts" status="status">
```

wherein 'rule' is a POJO with an arraylist 'parts'(which is also a list containing POJOs).

Inside the iterator, I'm including a jsp using `jsp:include`.

```
<s:iterator var="each_part" value="#request.rule.parts" status="eachpart">
    <jsp:include page="/jsp/edit_rule_part.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="id" value="<%=id%>" /> 
    </jsp:include>
```

In included jsp, i.e. edit_rule_part.jsp, I have one more iterator tag,

```
<s:iterator var="cond" value="#request.rule.parts.conditions">
```

But this does not work. I also tried using

```
<s:iterator var="cond" value="#each_part.conditions">
```

where 'each_part' is id of parent `s:iterator` in parent jsp, but it did not worked.

So structure looks like this

```
JSP1
    -s:iterator (id = 'each_part')
    -jsp:include
    -JSP2
         -s:iterator (id = 'cond')
```

So the problem is that 'cond' iterator in JSP2 wants to refer to 'each_part' iterator in JSP1.

How can I access the variable 'each_part' which is of type iterator in another iterator variable which is on another jsp file?

Usually we refer parent iterator in child iterator with value = #.list, but in this case both the iterators are on different jsps.

Earlier in struts1 this was achieved using nested-root tag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13762054/1700321.

Comment: Hey Aleksandr M, mine problem is different from what is mentioned in the link.

Comment: How it is different? You want to access some variable in the included jsp, right?

Comment: Yup, I want to access variable in included jsp, but it should be equivalent to nested-root in struts 1.x, which used to append the id of parent tags to all child tags by default.

Comment: To access it you need to pass it. So just do it. :)